# How to combine two queries in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

**query1:**

```
 $image= DB::table('products_photos')->groupBy('filename')
->get(['filename', DB::raw('MAX(id) as id')]);
```

This is my query to retreive single image for all the records stored.

**query2:**

```
$verifiedValues= priceInfo::join('productDescription', 
'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
   ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 
 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 
'productPriceDetails.productId')
   ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 
'productAdditionalInformation.productId')
 ->select('productPriceDetails.SKUID','productDescription.modelName')
   **->select($image)**
        ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', 
  "QCVerified")-

>where('productAdditionalInformation.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->where('productDescription.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->where('products_photos.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->where('productPriceDetails.listingStatus','=',"Inactive") 
     ->get();
```

This is my query where I have joined multiple tables and need to combine the query1 with query2.

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

error on combining both the queries

Comment: These two queries look very different to me, which probably rules out a union as a way to combine them.  Is there some way to use a join?  Can you include your table schema?  If you get stuck with Laravel, you can always go back to raw MySQL and work things out there first.

Comment: Why dont you work with the ORM? This simplyfies many queries like this. Other devs will hate you if they have to maintain queries like this. The ORM is a more fluent way to archieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you have two options. Either you try to merge the two resulting collections by using the `merge()` method, as it is explained via [Laravel :: Combine two DB query objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576134/laravel-combine-two-db-query-objects)

Or you use a join to combine the two queries in one single query. To keep your Builder object (without `get()`), you may use something like this:

```
$single_query = DB::table('first_query')
    ->join(DB::raw('('.$second_query->toSQL().') alias'), 'id', 'alias.id')
    ->mergeBindings($second_query)
    ->get();
```

You may omit the `mergeBindungs()` clause, if you dont have any parameters.